# CSV to JSON array conversion

Tags: python

I am trying to convert CSV file to JSON.

CSV File:

```
id,name,email
1,jim,test@gmail.com
1,jim,test2@gmail.com
2,kim,test3@gmail.com
```

Expected output

```
{"row" : {"id":1,"name":"jim","email": ["test@gmail.com","test1@gmail.com"]}},
{"row" : {"id":2,"name":"kim","email": "test3@gmail.com"}}
```

Comment: What have you tried and what exactly is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a little bit bulky implementation

```
import csv
import json

with open('data.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    # Get headers
    headers = next(reader, None)
    result = {}
    for row in reader:
        # Combine header and line to get a dict
        data = dict(zip(headers, row))
        if data['id'] not in result:
            data.update({'email': [data.pop('email')]})
            result[data['id']] = data
        else:
            # Aware if id and name fields are not consistant 
            assert data['name'] == result[data['id']]['name']
            result[data['id']]['email'].append(data['email'])

for rec in result.values():
    try:
        # try to unpack as a single value and if it fails leave as is
        rec['email'], = rec['email']
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print(json.dumps({'row': rec}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=None)
print(df)
#Output

     id name            email
  0   1  jim   test@gmail.com
  1   1  jim  test2@gmail.com
  2   2  kim  test3@gmail.com

df1 = df.groupby(['id', 'name'])['email'].apply(list).reset_index()
df_json = df1.to_json(orient='index')
print(df_json)

#Output:
{"0":{"id":1,"name":"jim","email":["test@gmail.com","test2@gmail.com"]},"1":{"id":2,"name":"kim","email":["test3@gmail.com"]}}
```

Comment: Thank you Aman for your response, but if one person has more than one email, I need them in an array.